# Can anyone please post working code to send email using sendgrid on Azure databse using PLSQL procedure

Tags: database, azure, plsql, sendgrid

I need a sample and working code to send email, using sendgrid authentication, using PLSQL procedure. Can anyone please post working code to send email using sendgrid on Azure database using PLSQL procedure.

sample and working code needed

Thank You in advance!!

Comment: @Sampath - added sample code

Comment: @shital kadu I was not able to see code please add in the above question

Comment: FYI this is off-topic, as it's just a requirement and you asking others to send you code. This isn't how the site works. Please read [ask], along with how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Sampath - links or sample code the OP may or may not have are irrelevant, as there's simply no programming question here. instead, it's a set of requirements and an expectation that the Community create a custom solution for said requirements. There is nothing to do here, aside from posting links to appropriate help content on Stack Overflow, and voting to close the question.